# Print the matched string using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match the string which is followed by " ETN : " i.e.,  (name1/name2 )   first  and after I match it, I want to print the first occurrence of it before the string "data reached"

```
ETN: name1/name2  

   abchsfk/jshflka/ZN                       (cellLVT)

   asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf/Z                    (mobSVT)

   asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf/Z        (celLVT)

   asjhdjs/jhskjds/ZN                       (abcSVT)

   shdsjk/jhskd/ZN                          (xyzSVT)

   name1/name2/ZN                 (abcLVT)    

   data reached



   asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf/Z        (celLVT)

   asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf/Z                    (mobSVT)

   shdsjk/jhskd/ZN                          (xyzSVT)

   asjhdjs/jhskjds/ZN                       (abcSVT)

   shdsjk/jhskd/ZN                          (xyzSVT)

   name1/name2/ZN                  (abcLVT)

ETN: name3/name4  

   abchsfk/jshflka/ZN                       (cellLVT)

   asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf/Z                    (mobSVT)

   asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf/Z        (celLVT)

   asjhdjs/jhskjds/ZN                       (abcSVT)

   shdsjk/jhskd/ZN                          (xyzSVT)

   name3/name4/ZN                 (fhLVT)    

   data reached



   asjhfdjkfd/sjfdskjfhdk/hsakfshf/Z        (celLVT)

   asjkfsa/sfklfkshfsf/Z                    (mobSVT)

   shdsjk/jhskd/ZN                          (xyzSVT)

   asjhdjs/jhskjds/ZN                       (abcSVT)

   shdsjk/jhskd/ZN                          (xyzSVT)

   name3/name4/ZN                  (fhLVT)
```

Output :

```
name1/name2/ZN                  (abcLVT)

name3/name4/ZN                 (fhLVT)
```

CODE:

I tried to march the string first with ETN and tried to print it.

```
if ($line =~ m/ETN: /)

        { 
    my @names = split / /, $line;

    $a = $names[3];

        if ($line =~ m /$a  /)

        { 
            print " $line \n" ; 
        }       

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't show the loop where you retrieve $line from the file but it looks like you're trying to use a nested approach, in which case you're missing another such  loop.  That would work if each record ends in "data reached", but that's not consistently present in your example data.  However a nested loop isn't necessary in this case nor does it add to readability, so just use a single loop as shown below.

First, a few comments:

- You don't need the m// for your regex as // will suffice since it's not a multi-line match.
- You should use an ^ anchor not only for accuracy but speed.
- You can retrieve the name from the regex without the split line you have by using the special match variables e.g. $1 as shown below.
- I didn't use $line in my code below, just the assumed $_ var, which is common perl style.  Since it's assumed, it wasn't written in the code.
- If you don't chomp the line, you don't need to add a newline when printing.

Here's your code, with the input loop shown, modified to work. I used $name in two conditionals below, which is equivalent to checking if it is both defined and not empty.

```
my $name;
while (<$in>)
{
    if (/^ETN:\s+(\S+)/) { $name = $1 }
    elsif ( $name and /^\s+$name/) { print }
}  
$name or warn("No ETN records found\n");
```

Comment: Thank you the explanation. I was trying to write the code, still learning. Your explanation is really useful. I will work on it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple regex for this. Try the following code:

```
if ($inputstring =~ m/ENT:.*?($name1/$name2)ZN/) {
    print "$1\t$2"
}
```

`$name1` and `$name2` will be the strings to match. This will print:

```
name1 tab name2
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this approach

Comment: You only have one capturing group, so `$2` won't be set. But if you already have the variables `$name1` and `$name2`, there's no need to capture them in the first place.