# print the matched word in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I need to print all my matched strings from a stored line in perl. I have seen various posts on this 
[Print the matched string using perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404125/print-the-matched-string-using-perl)
[Perl Regex - Print the matched value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617314/perl-regex-print-the-matched-value)

and I experimented to first try to print the first word. But I get a build error

```
Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at rg.pl line 10.
```

I have tried with split and arrays and it works, but while printing $1, it throws error.

My code is here

```
#!/usr/bin/perl/
use warnings;
use strict;


#my $line = "At a far distance near the bar, was a parked car. Star were shining in the night. The boy in the car had scar and he was at war with his enemy. \n";

my $line = "At a far distance near the bar, was a parked car. \n";
if($line =~ /[a-z]ar/gi)
{       print "$1 \n";   }

$_ = $line;
```

I want my output for this code to be

```
far
```

and subsequently print all the words containing ar,

```
far
near
bar
parked 
car
```

I even tried changing my code, as below but that didnt work, same error

```
if($line =~ /[a-z]ar/gi)  {
        my $match = $1;
        print "$match \n"; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you didn't *capture* anything, which is how `$n` variables are populated. Put parenthesis around what you want to be captured into `$1`

```
if ($line =~ /([a-z]ar)i/) { print "$1\n" }
```

I've removed the `/g` which is unneeded (and with potential for trouble<sup>†</sup>) here.

Next, your pattern requires and captures one letter followed by literal `ar`, no more no less. That won't capture `near`, nor will it capture `parked` (it'll get `par` only).  It will not even match a word that *starts* with `ar`, since it requires that there is a letter before `ar`. You need to use [quantifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Matching-repetitions), to tell it how many times to match a letter. And you also want to find all matches.

One way is to scoop them all up by providing the *list [context](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context)* and `/g` (*global*) [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)

```
my @words = $line =~ /([a-z]*ar[a-z]*)/gi;

print "$_\n" for @words;
```

The `[a-z]*` means to match a letter, zero-or-more times. So an optional string of letters. We also added an optional string of letters after `ar`. The `/g` makes it continue through the string after a match, to find all such patterns. In the list context the list of matches is returned.

Or, you can match in *scalar context* like in the first example, but in a `while` loop

```
while ($line =~ /([a-z]*ar[a-z]*)/gi) { print "$1\n" }
```

Here `/g` does something different. It matches a pattern once and returns true, the `while` condition is true and we print. Then it comes back and looks for a match *from where it matched previously* ... and keeps doing this until there are no more matches.

This is complex behavior altogether. From [Regexp Quote-Like Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

> The `/g` modifier specifies global pattern matching--that is, matching as many times as possible within the string. How it behaves depends on the context. In list context, it returns a list of the substrings matched by any capturing parentheses in the regular expression. If there are no parentheses, it returns a list of all the matched strings, as if there were parentheses around the whole pattern.
>
> In scalar context, each execution of `m//g` finds the next match, returning true if it matches, and false if there is no further match.   [...]

Read about this in more detail and in a tutorial manner [in perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl), under "*Global matching*."

---

<sup>†</sup> *Note on using `/g` modifier in scalar context*

I've used that above, in `while (/.../g)`, what is a very common way to hop over all occurrences of the pattern in a string, each time giving us control in the `while` body.

While this use is intended and idiomatic, the use of `/g` in scalar context can bring subtle trouble when not in the loop condition: the next regex with `/g` on this variable  will continue from the previous match, not from the string's beginning, what may be unexpected.

That "next regex" may also simply be that same expression -- in the next pass of some larger loop in which our expression happens to be, and this holds across function calls as well. Consider

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $s = q(one two three);

sub func { say $1 if $_[0] =~ /(\w+)/g };  # /g may be of great consequence!

for (1..4) {
    # ... perhaps much, much later ...
    func($s);
}
```

This loop prints lines `one`, then `two`, then `three`, and that's that.  This (working) example is so bare bones that it is artificial bit I hope that it conveys that `/g` in scalar context may surprise.

For one thing, it is not uncommon to see `/g` on a regex in an `if` condition being plain wrong.

Comment: Can you please kindly explain a bit more, How are these two different in working?  if ($line =~ /([a-z]ar)i/) { print "$1\n" }           if($line =~ /[a-z]ar/gi)
{       print "$1 \n";   }

Comment: One is a global match (`g`), the other is not.

Comment: No, I mean the capturing part How are you doing it?

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji  Yes ... I thought I did in the answer.  With `/[a-z]ar/` you match, so the `if` returns true.  But the match isn't _captured_, so there is nothing in `$1`.  The `$n` variables get filled with things that are _captured_ (by parenthesis).  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, I did not know about parenthesis doing the capture. Thanks.

Comment: So, how to capture parked and near?

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji  The second example gets all of them and puts them in `@words`.  Is that OK?  I am adding a capture-as-you-go way as well ...

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji I've added a more complete description/commentary. Will edit more as I review.

Comment: This is _massive_ overkill for such a simple question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, perhaps.  I keep failing to provide _minimal_ answers.  I mean, they ask about how to capture globally.   It is probably the most used feature of regex, and it is complex. I feel like I'd leave them shorthanded, almost cheated, if i just gave the direct answer in one line of code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Thank you for the response (and for the vote)! Of course, you raised a perfectly good point, of getting the best-fitting extent of the answer, and keeping it as concise as feasible.  I just don't yet know how to get that measure right.

Comment: (... and I prefer to err on the side of giving too much rather than perhaps too little.  Just came upon this exchange and would like to add: I still didn't figure out the "best" measure, and I still prefer to err on the "perhaps too much" side.)

Answer (score 2):

For multiple matches, use a `while` loop.  Also, I surrounded the quantity you want to capture with parentheses to indicate that it is a *capture* group.

```
while ($line =~ /([a-z]*ar[a-z]*)/gi ) {
    print "$1 \n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Are you using substitution here? s//// Didnt get that part.

Comment: This `/([a-z]+ar)/`  will not capture `parked`, nor will it match words that _start_ with `ar` (it requires a letter before `ar`).